# Convert textarea field scrollheight property to HTML 'rows'

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I am trying to convert a textarea field's height that I get of with java script's 'scrollheight' property to HTML's 'rows' attribute. Anyone know how to do this?

I am capturing / storing scrollheight with changes to the textarea's height so that with the next load of that textarea, it will remember the height. This all works great ... except I need a reliable way to do the conversion for all browsers. If I can't convert, how else can I go about this? Would I have to load the form and then run java code to adjust all the textarea heights? The code I am using is below.

I use the textarea mouseup event which fires the following code

```
function settextareaheight(t, id){
var height = document.getElementById(id);
height.value = t.scrollHeight ;
}
```

It gets the scrollHeight of the textarea and saves it to a form field (and then the database with a post).

I display the textarea with HTML and php (there are many textarea fields on the form with corresponding text fields to store their "scrollheight" attribute, so the textarea mousdown passes along the unique id of its corresponding text field):

```
<textarea readonly cols="80" rows="1" style="max-width:625px; min-width:625px" onmouseup ="settextareaheight(this, '<? echo 'gheight'.$i ?>')"><? echo htmlspecialchars($gem['descr']) ?></textarea>
```

Comment: The problem is that scrollHeight is expressed in pixels while a single row's height (if you want it expressed in pixels) is dependant on which font (and related styling) you are using in your css. BTW inthe first line you typed "java" but I guess you mean Javascript right?

Comment: So if I use my css pixel setting, will this be a reliable conversion? I currently use percentages e.g. font-size:120% in the css. How to go about doing the conversion? Thanks for javascript reminder, I corrected the post - I'm still new with javascript ...

Comment: I found a good table link [here](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/css-font-size-conversion-chart/) for the conversion. I will test it out.

Comment: Yes the table may help but try to have some extra space as different browsers behave in different ways and may not conform to that table. Your best bet in my opinion is to have the text in pixels, as you said above it would be more reliable.